# How to keep a variables value outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions that take input from a drop down menu using onchange

```
  <script>

 current_fin = "none";
 current_mat = "Pine";



// Pass the current selection into a variable to use.
function getMaterial()
{
    var mat = document.getElementById("dropdownone");
    var current_mat = mat.options[mat.selectedIndex].text;
$("#price").html("Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>" +"Finish is: " + current_fin);
}
function getFinish()
{
    var fin = document.getElementById("dropdowntwo");
     var current_fin = fin.options[fin.selectedIndex].text;
$("#price").html("Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>" +"Finish is: " + current_fin);
}
</script>
```

All it does is write the value of what was selected to a div #price. Now the problem arises when I change one and then the other. If I switch between the two boxes the variables revert to their default value none and pine. I want them to retain the value outside of the function, so if i switch box 1 to oak it stays as that until I switch it back. I have a feeling I have scope problems here but don't know how to proceed. I'll include the HTML for reference.

```
<select name="material" id="dropdownone" onchange="getMaterial()">
  <option>Pine</option>
  <option>Oak</option>
  <option>Walnut</option>
  <option>Plastic</option>
</select>

<select name="finish" id="dropdowntwo" onchange="getFinish()">
  <option>None</option>
  <option>Finished</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit To Cart">


<div id=price>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>   

     var current_fin = "none";
     var current_mat = "Pine";   


    // Pass the current selection into a variable to use.
    function getMaterial()
    {
        var mat = document.getElementById("dropdownone");
        current_mat = mat.options[mat.selectedIndex].text;
        $("#price").html("Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>" +"Finish is: " + current_fin);
    }

    function getFinish()
    {
        var fin = document.getElementById("dropdowntwo");
         current_fin = fin.options[fin.selectedIndex].text;
        $("#price").html("Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>" +"Finish is: " + current_fin);
    }
```

When you write `var current_mat` inside a function, it overrides the global `current_mat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

current_fin = "none";
current_mat = "Pine";

function getMaterial()
{
 var mat = document.getElementById("dropdownone");
 var current_mat = mat.options[mat.selectedIndex].text;
 var fin = document.getElementById("dropdowntwo");
 var current_fin = fin.options[fin.selectedIndex].text;
 document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>"   +"Finish is: " + current_fin;
}
function getFinish()
{
var fin = document.getElementById("dropdowntwo");
var current_fin = fin.options[fin.selectedIndex].text;
var mat = document.getElementById("dropdownone");
var current_mat = mat.options[mat.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="Material is: " + current_mat  + "<br/>" +"Finish is: " + current_fin;
}


  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <select name="material" id="dropdownone" onchange="getMaterial()">
   <option>Pine</option>
   <option>Oak</option>
   <option>Walnut</option>
   <option>Plastic</option>
  </select>

   <select name="finish" id="dropdowntwo" onchange="getFinish()">
      <option>None</option>
      <option>Finished</option>
   </select>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit To Cart">

   <div id="price">

   </div>

    </body>
     </html>
```